# GridViewColumn with no cells?

Tags: wpf, xaml, gridviewcolumn, celltemplate

Is it possible to have 3 GridViewColumn but only 2 CellTemplate ?
I want the first cell to "occupy" the 2 left columns ?

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can do it directly, but you can however create two regular columns, and then make the header of the first one with a line in the middle, so it would look like it's two cells.

Comment: Toda, but I thought of that, the problem is that I am getting into the issue of default header behaviors like mouse over or click events. I need each header to be independent in this sense.